# Airflow connection error with google cloud sql

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I have an airflow instance running on AWS - EC2 and I'm trying to connect with google cloud sql.

I've access the EC2 machine trough SSH and ran google cloud proxy command to instantiate my connection with GCP.

```
sudo ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=instance_name:us-central1:dbname=tcp:3308 -credential_file=****-22388-929422105353.json &
```

With this connection I've successfully connected to GCP SQL for my Postgresql instance, using the PostgreSQL connector on airflow.

But I'm not able to connect with my MySQL instance, using the MySQL connector, due to this error:

```
(2006, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

When I tried to connect trough Google Cloud SQL connector using the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/gcp_sql.html).
I get another error but with a blank error description:
[airflow connection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNXnI.png)

I have a PostgreSQL running locally on my EC2 as the airflow database, I don't know if this made my PostgreSQL connection to work. Should I have an local instance of MySQL?
What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of airflow are you using? Also, do you get any error on the Stackdriver logs on MySQL aside from the one you shared?

Comment: @rsalinas, I'm using airflow version 1.10.9. I don't know how to check any other logs, the Logs option on Browse menu show an empty list